# The use of a normal distribution in Torch prevents the reinforcement learning agent from learning

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, torch

When converting Gaussian noise from a numpy array to a tensor matrix, the agent inexplicably stops learning. Even after debugging, I observe that the noise matrices appear similar. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

The original numpy method that functions properly:

```
    def _add_gaussian_noise(self, mask, std_dev, max_n):
        noise = np.random.normal(0, std_dev, (self.n_nodes, self.n_nodes))
        noise = np.clip(noise, 0, max_n)
        noise = np.round(noise)
        noise *= mask
        return noise
```

The torch tensor that doesn't work:

```
    @torch.no_grad()
    def _add_gaussian_noise(self, mask, std_dev, max_n):
        noise = torch.normal(0, std_dev, (self.n_nodes, self.n_nodes), device=self.device)
        noise = torch.clamp(noise, 0, max_n)
        noise = torch.round(noise)
        noise *= mask
        return noise
```

Comment: Have you checked if your gradient dies after adding the noise? Are you sure you need the `no_grad` decorator?

Comment: Adding or removing no_grad doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What about tracking the magnitude of the gradient through the network and seeing where they could be dying off?